# How to solve the Crash issue using Crash Log?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have crash issue when I click on button of alertView, and i get crash log, which i listed below and I also listed below the method of alertview's ClickedButtonAtIndex: in which my app is crash, so can anybody help me?

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSLog(@"~Log : Class:%@ Method:%@",NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));    

    if(buttonIndex == 1 && [textView text]!= NULL && ![[textView text] isEqualToString:@""]) {

        if([[[textView text] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] length] > 0) {

            NSArray *aryConsult = [aryConsults objectAtIndex:iPath.row];

            for (int i=0; i < [aryConsult  count]; i++) {

                if([[[aryConsult objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
                    ConsultsDB *consultDB = [[ConsultsDB alloc] init];
                    NSManagedObject *mgObject = (NSManagedObject *)[aryConsult objectAtIndex:i];
                    [mgObject setValue:@"0" forKey:@"status"];
                    [mgObject setValue:[[textView text] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                                        [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] forKey:@"followUpDesc"];
                    [mgObject setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"completionDate"];
                                        [consultDB updateConsults:mgObject];        
                    [consultDB release];
                }
            }           
            [self refreshView];
        }
    }


    [CommonMethods updateTheUIForToDoListScreen];
    [CommonMethods updateTheUIForHistoryAndPhysical];


}
```

My Crash log is :-

```
Incident Identifier: 96E6BA22-9F10-4A23-97AB-CEF9F78D715B
CrashReporter Key:   f2dec3bb7202b9b2fb0a68f76b4a36a85a382e2f
Hardware Model:      iPad3,1
Process:         MedPRO Inpatient Manager [535]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/3BEEDA35-AD04-4629-A9D8-1481DFA936C5/MedPRO Inpatient Manager.app/MedPRO Inpatient Manager
Identifier:      MedPRO Inpatient Manager
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-10-08 12:33:57.417 +0530
OS Version:      iOS 6.0 (10A403)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000f
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x316f25b0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   MedPRO Inpatient Manager        0x00031a86 -[ConsultsViewController alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:] (ConsultsViewController.m:802)
2   UIKit                           0x35db3b74 -[UIAlertView(Private) _buttonClicked:] + 292
3   UIKit                           0x35d470a8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 68
4   UIKit                           0x35d4705a -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 26
5   UIKit                           0x35d47038 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 40
6   UIKit                           0x35d468ee -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 498
7   UIKit                           0x35d46de4 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 484
8   UIKit                           0x35c6f5f4 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 520
9   UIKit                           0x35c5c804 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 376
10  UIKit                           0x35c5c11e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6150
11  GraphicsServices                0x34c595a0 _PurpleEventCallback + 588
12  GraphicsServices                0x34c591ce PurpleEventCallback + 30
13  CoreFoundation                  0x38dad170 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
14  CoreFoundation                  0x38dad112 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
15  CoreFoundation                  0x38dabf94 __CFRunLoopRun + 1380
16  CoreFoundation                  0x38d1eeb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
17  CoreFoundation                  0x38d1ed44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
18  GraphicsServices                0x34c582e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
19  UIKit                           0x35cb02fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
20  MedPRO Inpatient Manager        0x00002fa4 main (main.m:14)
21  MedPRO Inpatient Manager        0x00002f64 start + 36

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37812d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33188cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33188a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x331888a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37802648 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x31f96974 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 792
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x31f96654 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 32

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37801eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37802048 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x38dad040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3   CoreFoundation                  0x38dabd9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
4   CoreFoundation                  0x38d1eeb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x38d1ed44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                         0x35130a70 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 440
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3319330e _pthread_start + 306
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x331931d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37812d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33188cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33188a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x331888a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37812d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33188cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33188a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x331888a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37812d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33188cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33188a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x331888a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37812d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33188cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33188a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x331888a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x006ba0e0    r1: 0x360cf529      r2: 0x006ba0e0      r3: 0x360cf529
    r4: 0x00000007    r5: 0x00000001      r6: 0x006a2390      r7: 0x2fdfe7c4
    r8: 0x3ada01ac    r9: 0x0d833d4a     r10: 0x006b9b70     r11: 0x00000001
    ip: 0x38d22919    sp: 0x2fdfe75c      lr: 0x00031a8b      pc: 0x316f25b0
  cpsr: 0x20070030

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -   0x152fff +MedPRO Inpatient Manager armv7  <d06665a92fa2336084091dec46ea087a> /var/mobile/Applications/3BEEDA35-AD04-4629-A9D8-1481DFA936C5/MedPRO Inpatient Manager.app/MedPRO Inpatient Manager
 0xac78000 -  0xac88fff  Riven armv7  <08ac9e94f78e366dad2c70bd9ccdea11> /System/Library/TextInput/Riven.bundle/Riven
0x2fe7e000 - 0x2fe9efff  dyld armv7  <75594988728831d98e1f7c4c7b7ca29d> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30dd1000 - 0x30fa9fff  ImageIO armv7  <fdfa8aa6307235b29435e5c8f6bc9819> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x3131c000 - 0x31358fff  DataAccess armv7  <bd40f7ec5a9c3df7b4a575fffc25c14f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x3139d000 - 0x313d2fff  libcorecrypto.dylib armv7  <ebd023957d853fa8bd35309592e92dac> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x313d3000 - 0x313d7fff  IncomingCallFilter armv7  <e938b3977503385087928a65367f849c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IncomingCallFilter.framework/IncomingCallFilter
0x31419000 - 0x3152efff  QuartzCore armv7  <d96571a6986c3012b315cb860f4d65ca> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x315ff000 - 0x3163dfff  VideoToolbox armv7  <bfc75ceef01e366e8335949abf037d4b> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x31645000 - 0x316aafff  CoreMedia armv7  <d227864b757e3a7ea5d7d96dcbb948fe> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x316de000 - 0x316defff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <8a2e3a8fdf9335e2867a33e2d1a9baf8> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x316ef000 - 0x317edfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <5224e803eca737a4b2c6451d136b3d28> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x31814000 - 0x31832fff  WebBookmarks armv7  <012ed1a1f54a3d6d836e2836781d4f73> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x3187b000 - 0x3187cfff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <46cd200d99323aebbf6d81e5fb16424f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x318b9000 - 0x31a5ffff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <6b14c224c0e0306aa9084679ec6a99d2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x31aa6000 - 0x31c57fff  libmecabra.dylib armv7  <b59b3ee949633384bf5612da5cc73781> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x31c58000 - 0x31c64fff  AccountSettings armv7  <0b7524e9a8ef36bf9e9f6a5c445478af> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x31c69000 - 0x31eeefff  MediaToolbox armv7  <a1df6dd0733233d3b1cba9cddf3991f6> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x31eef000 - 0x31f1dfff  Security armv7  <be87724ccad837479efd45ca9f2c6b2c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x31f7a000 - 0x31f8dfff  AirTraffic armv7  <b588b9fdc83d369db76f1ad5ebf2a4fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirTraffic.framework/AirTraffic
0x31f8e000 - 0x31fabfff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <4abccf75caf33fa5a0c6037b2e1c5f41> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x31fb6000 - 0x31fb6fff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <85e7546accc23ae1a973da4758512b7f> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x320bd000 - 0x321fbfff  vImage armv7  <a7fd7fcd7041356db2ca297402ab6e8c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x3221a000 - 0x3221afff  Accelerate armv7  <22bee3e96cbc3538bfc50ca5be618cc0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x3223c000 - 0x32292fff  CoreAudio armv7  <a3a2eb3a29443b42a23aa8ecb1232846> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x322a8000 - 0x322b1fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <43de6d03af0838f2a1eeec10d4149e9d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x322b4000 - 0x322effff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <7a68e65e523030faa9d91478e939bc00> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x324f8000 - 0x324fdfff  Marco armv7  <755b00548c863f939bf1409f03f2b3ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x32539000 - 0x3253dfff  CertUI armv7  <7e4aee03dc3735559f1270e504d94f02> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x32547000 - 0x32549fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <e57152bacb36350e8a023e0c1b540a0c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x32555000 - 0x32558fff  MobileSystemServices armv7  <6edd9c74c5a73c33809152446abe1538> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x3272e000 - 0x3276bfff  FTServices armv7  <aa7fe75a69d538b2a80efa63e3484b2a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x33008000 - 0x33061fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <d831f1f9285535acac5035a29d84aaaf> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x33062000 - 0x33077fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <3afeeea531013420af75315d8d6dd332> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x33118000 - 0x33181fff  IMAVCore armv7  <38d0b133ac043f08a5dc90ea80f516f4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMAVCore.framework/IMAVCore
0x33182000 - 0x33208fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <d45dc8901531343caf9b7e703d3eba50> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x33209000 - 0x33225fff  libsystem_m.dylib armv7  <7b2a25c750063de480f6a691f716b9d7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x33226000 - 0x3330cfff  AVFoundation armv7  <23a8a62a06b03cbcbe7659918951c9f3> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x3330d000 - 0x33366fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <ad4c53081a263f0d96f63b9a80f2ae91> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x33368000 - 0x33413fff  MediaControlSender armv7  <fba51e235adc368b8132db578723a8fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x3353f000 - 0x3368dfff  MusicLibrary armv7  <262f509dae9f3c128f25163a7029685b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x336a9000 - 0x336bbfff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <131d8cf4df333df3b8487ef93438e27c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x33714000 - 0x3371dfff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <5258dce78afc3fd7934a5674b92ad785> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x3371e000 - 0x337e3fff  CFNetwork armv7  <3e973794a4d13428bb974edcb2027139> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x337e4000 - 0x337e5fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <6a0dd04f0710329b9c1722db2235f5c3> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x337e6000 - 0x3383bfff  CoreTelephony armv7  <54708e241c5c3e2297c2fca0d685497d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x33848000 - 0x3384efff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <6c1c1aaf9a3537d7ada4b519d14da7ab> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x3384f000 - 0x338d6fff  CoreMotion armv7  <537e5776244f3ef5a355f8fd14a72a22> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x33a3b000 - 0x33a3cfff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <6c912cedc1e938ad914dfce91a529b68> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x33a57000 - 0x33a92fff  AppSupport armv7  <74ed50d2f7d23ce696b029dd817749c0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x33a93000 - 0x33aa2fff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <5c91ef875c5931a1a26e227ddfd7262d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x33aac000 - 0x33ae7fff  iCalendar armv7  <d5f593ead35b38a98d6cfd4a243e0172> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x33aeb000 - 0x33b0ffff  Bom armv7  <c76b4156e0463ecb922608d44c126d86> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x33b10000 - 0x33b72fff  CoreText armv7  <4a0bece315e9316fa1aa1b5923740f55> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x33cd9000 - 0x33cdefff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <3a351ca1d4ae3146a787f3e13564294b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x33d0a000 - 0x33d0bfff  DataMigration armv7  <25f8874067393208acc083124bc3eb86> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x33d0c000 - 0x33d1dfff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <22255260ec6436d19176696422441c40> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x33d25000 - 0x33d2bfff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <9e8bfe02e370375ea8439ab895528982> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x33d2c000 - 0x33d44fff  AssistantServices armv7  <a1444bc3ce433abb8dad2010d43cb41d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssistantServices.framework/AssistantServices
0x33d45000 - 0x33d4afff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <021ff140d6003f3281dfa29b79fa9e6e> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x33d4b000 - 0x33d64fff  Notes armv7  <b8fb864f5973319083f926d9a570734e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x33e4d000 - 0x33fe5fff  MediaPlayer armv7  <45ee55956c693d8cb16dc4c4e85075e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x34048000 - 0x3406efff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <134c41c587fb33dca014bd525f68a0c7> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x34078000 - 0x34082fff  MailServices armv7  <f31a7844317a3f2484cffe092e9fd7c2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x34083000 - 0x3408cfff  MediaRemote armv7  <dbc251adcad43e72a31427f836a060cd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
0x340a8000 - 0x340aafff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <7add7c91a2673641b0c5f0433a203da6> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x34167000 - 0x34168fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <3a149b4730663b1ea84e4a0a68ccc689> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x3417e000 - 0x3425afff  WebKit armv7  <73fa195f63bc32c29060ac0fecabdca6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x3425b000 - 0x3425dfff  OAuth armv7  <d3e2bc9ae64b31f0a89c52dc1c2797fc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
0x3426b000 - 0x3429bfff  ContentIndex armv7  <25cc27c7fdac34e6ae5e057c048a3e21> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x342a9000 - 0x342affff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <a81d768a49cf37a1a111594d39cea3fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x342e9000 - 0x342f7fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <d0fb0eda6cb53a4da859d598c59e7522> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x3460a000 - 0x348bffff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <dd6f3958c3d536d6be90836682d2ffee> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x348e5000 - 0x348e5fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <993c9bfe8bf031548b9ddba63cc17015> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x349ba000 - 0x349cffff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <e79b59a3406f34d9b37f8085955115ce> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x34c53000 - 0x34c5efff  GraphicsServices armv7  <c5879083e8693aba827c78a32abe2391> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x34c8e000 - 0x34d7cfff  GeoServices armv7  <6af26ce81030330b97122ba8c1deaaa2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x34e31000 - 0x34efbfff  Celestial armv7  <1a048f93218d3551984b2d07e884694c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x34f37000 - 0x34f54fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <8e4d21f987d4334e927222c28ff1130b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x3510d000 - 0x35111fff  FTClientServices armv7  <13aa63aa5e2e348ea289e0fd16585890> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x35112000 - 0x35114fff  MessageSupport armv7  <44d449b4959a33b99d4ab4a9cd161ee6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MessageSupport.framework/MessageSupport
0x35115000 - 0x35121fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <a3bba3842596315a81aa171a8bbda7b5> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x35126000 - 0x35a55fff  WebCore armv7  <cd34aedf72653d1dbef6b14fdfd0c053> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x35a69000 - 0x35a76fff  TelephonyUtilities armv7  <0e07c7484ca63c189fd19790eb48bb28> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities.framework/TelephonyUtilities
0x35a8b000 - 0x35a91fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <690aaa493b5c3f9582499f174adf4964> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x35acd000 - 0x35ae5fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <be3d5625aed733ffb2d53400655fe110> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x35ae6000 - 0x35b01fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <6e5f3b4c18e137e0a464fe13095b7dab> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x35bad000 - 0x35beafff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <7db25f3d55b93f31868e37326fba1e57> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x35c59000 - 0x361acfff  UIKit armv7  <98789fe7c21b3fe0bf5c0bb36648147f> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x36201000 - 0x3624dfff  IMFoundation armv7  <b1a5542b977e3ae683f40ee5755d5b32> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x3624e000 - 0x362d3fff  MessageUI armv7  <acd711b4e9cb3bdba768a884c4d6976a> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x362d4000 - 0x362e0fff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <74d50f4c8d243a35ad3ae89d85f2793a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x362e1000 - 0x36567fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <6a4804d0e35e362dbad6f047c25227ca> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x36682000 - 0x3673bfff  Message armv7  <c854843dec583b33a72a9fe047d20f0c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x3673c000 - 0x36761fff  OpenCL armv7  <f7706501012430fc94ed99006419fba9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x368cb000 - 0x368cbfff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <f2cad3bd15f63f448a9c5be732c65819> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x368cc000 - 0x36981fff  CoreImage armv7  <ba744c4f6a1c3c0598de9d429022093a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x36989000 - 0x36a43fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <5c030d99a0113ceda2ae375d348e4cdb> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x36a44000 - 0x36a47fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <e6b6ae9d4f5f3831a40fcc370afc1429> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x36a92000 - 0x36accfff  iTunesStore armv7  <4ff9158eb0583316b34506904b21a4f3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iTunesStore.framework/iTunesStore
0x36ae8000 - 0x36b15fff  MobileAsset armv7  <23e6b8ea85dd3dea84d8c295b4777753> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x36b16000 - 0x36b22fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <0338ce49444332ec88cfc45c624bb39b> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x36b2e000 - 0x36b33fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <7bde3532f2953f3894eb725379575926> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x36b34000 - 0x36b7efff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <a361a382693032b9bdfb2860033b3024> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x36bb8000 - 0x36bc7fff  CoreVideo armv7  <092f3aa965803a1aaea69af2ac5143f5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x36dcd000 - 0x36e24fff  SAObjects armv7  <93fe8149b03538edb4b78bd374050a00> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SAObjects.framework/SAObjects
0x36e38000 - 0x36e44fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <e98708fbfa683df2a91d45dc765071a7> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x36e8f000 - 0x36fc7fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <903960bfcfe93adb943752851f88491e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x36fc8000 - 0x36fdbfff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <c5a5f03138353747b539e620ef2bb5c0> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x36fe4000 - 0x370d1fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <faa5abb937e3306ab87c7f7c38315839> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x37134000 - 0x37551fff  TextInput armv7  <ee57be9a7f723604afa6f27f85ea8b1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x37613000 - 0x3768bfff  IMCore armv7  <552805a4634630bbaad2bc9d862d7196> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x376a0000 - 0x376b6fff  VoiceServices armv7  <9f5307bc0cf3398e8b0770d924acb29e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VoiceServices.framework/VoiceServices
0x376b7000 - 0x376b8fff  IOAccelerator armv7  <de8af6be681832008d180d7424d55f0d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x376b9000 - 0x376cffff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <9b3fd56781103f209be2c43e48c1efc9> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x3779c000 - 0x37800fff  AddressBook armv7  <3c0d5a3207cf3771b0beb0cd8e8a6e12> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x37801000 - 0x37817fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <f167dacec44b3a86a8eee73400ff7a83> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x37818000 - 0x3788cfff  ProofReader armv7  <cc89a352199a393ba0e46af69e670ef9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x37946000 - 0x3794bfff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <15aa2c3c8d523273913d4fc6717d3b7c> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x379dc000 - 0x37a59fff  HomeSharing armv7  <9126a007a413357b8c0275cc505cb197> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
0x37a9c000 - 0x37a9ffff  ActorKit armv7  <64235ea1a8b73d23a4a9836410424b6b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x37aba000 - 0x37b03fff  IOKit armv7  <c4786e65ac913839b1bb3b85a9c951fa> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x37c8b000 - 0x37c8bfff  vecLib armv7  <66204595f7653ef29e5e26cb8629177a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x37cca000 - 0x37cd1fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <257ecb171a363e4298a63f72d7fffea2> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x37cd2000 - 0x37e95fff  Foundation armv7  <2e1ac190c4f837e2a1059043dd7b1c63> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x37e96000 - 0x37e9dfff  OpenGLES armv7  <e035b741746c316dba8f1e59a568bf17> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x37ef6000 - 0x37ef6fff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <a04b639c18593885bd81bfa623a6f07c> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x37f26000 - 0x37f2dfff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <c1a469c6ca4a3718bef325ec0f4e1885> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x37f6e000 - 0x37f7ffff  Accounts armv7  <07b95faa96e73ffeb52694cbad7f3528> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x37f83000 - 0x37f94fff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <a3d025234d1a3880a0e5f87879633ee0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x37fe6000 - 0x37feafff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <6a8f59f89218372d9f24c4193a179008> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x37ff9000 - 0x3802ffff  MIME armv7  <32427c81a9933c4796d1a37a88a3ac44> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x3816b000 - 0x3824efff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <56d8e00447133cd89457deec007327cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x383c7000 - 0x383e7fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <7f6f63b31f333c41952f685fdd54a6cb> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x38427000 - 0x38472fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <55a7612b28c43cfcad7089b688591b80> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x38473000 - 0x3847afff  XPCObjects armv7  <5bc4f7282e9d3945a6c1885217670667> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
0x3847b000 - 0x3847efff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <2a9fe0b48f473d0f8fe2bf076cd12753> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x385c8000 - 0x38620fff  CoreLocation armv7  <3235bde1608331bebc291891405896c6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x38648000 - 0x38649fff  CoreSurface armv7  <b3f9d4e8dd803a48b88c58a0663d92a3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x38a6d000 - 0x38b20fff  EventKit armv7  <8dbff0bfcf833661827a76b9adb64d70> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x38b28000 - 0x38b80fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <9d006173bfcc3001b45c44b8e78833ed> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x38bc6000 - 0x38bc8fff  TCC armv7  <f641dd0500fa3f0087d93da665ea84b8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x38bcf000 - 0x38bf2fff  MobileSync armv7  <986186369add34f1be231f5a47d2fd2c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x38c14000 - 0x38cecfff  StoreServices armv7  <9da3466c9cf13402a9f0412065f0ada7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x38d16000 - 0x38e48fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <e30fc309df7b3c9f8ac57f0f6047d65f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x38e49000 - 0x3925cfff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <0cb7a12beb3d32c1abd1834be8328b7c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x39287000 - 0x3929cfff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <9fbb123276823c2383fc34b7a55404d7> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x3936b000 - 0x39372fff  libsystem_notify.dylib armv7  <6e39f8511ecc3c3489829714eb6fde12> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x39373000 - 0x3938cfff  DictionaryServices armv7  <e1f8d258d02c344cb0d17cec31818d3f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x3938d000 - 0x39390fff  libcache.dylib armv7  <e08b913e17753180b91728a8bd5dda7b> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x393bc000 - 0x393c5fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e51cbfefefbc30b6b47d99739123033e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x397d6000 - 0x397eefff  EAP8021X armv7  <034c653573c233f08edf67e516d66097> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x397ef000 - 0x397f3fff  IOSurface armv7  <1f598a3806073bdaa906c51dccc9429e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x398ac000 - 0x398dffff  AppleAccount armv7  <2af09d814a5a382192613b68b9327d49> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x399f8000 - 0x399f8fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <b25697291f6237feb3458df23485a759> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x39a01000 - 0x39a0efff  ApplePushService armv7  <60dbc7ab243435e099e19bdd3fa83dbb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
```

Comment: What is line 802 in your code? You probably have a dangling pointer there.

Comment: You can set a symbolic breakpoint for objc_exception_throw. This will probably give you more information on what causes the crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main hint is `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` which you kind almost get everytime there is something wrong with your memory management. You are trying to send a message to a deallocated instance and my guess is it is

```
ConsultsDB *consultDB = [[ConsultsDB alloc] init];
NSManagedObject *mgObject = (NSManagedObject *)[aryConsult objectAtIndex:i];
```

Have you checked that mgObject and aryConsult are not `nil` ?

You maybe can get more information if you use a exception breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Place your app and the .dSYM file (got generated when you build and run the app:) in a folder on desktop:

OPEN terminal application,then go to the folder created on the desktop like this

cd Desktop/(Folder Name)

Then use below command to get line number of crash:

atos -arch armv7 -o YourAppFile.app/'App Name' MEMORY_LOCATION_OF_CRASH_IN_CRASH_LOG.

Ex: atos -arch armv7 -o 'App Name.app'/'App Name' 0x00002fa4

It will give the line number and function Name in the code where your app get crashed.

As in your case Thread 0 Crashed:

20  MedPRO Inpatient Manager        0x00002fa4 main (main.m:14)

It is the last line in stack where your app get crashed so use '0x00002fa4' as memory location of crash

Comment: Thank you but it gives me "atos cannot load symbols for the file MedPro.app/MedPro for architecture armv7." now what can I do?

Comment: Using atos with the app binary will never give you a line number. Also the crash report already shows line numbers. There is no additional information that can be grabbed. @Pfitz answer gives a hint on the cause of the crash. This tip is of no help and also content wise wrong.

Comment: Hi Radhu, as your crash report already seems symbolicated you dont need to use those commands, but for error:
"atos cannot load symbols for the file MedPro.app/MedPro for architecture armv7."
,just for future reference:
It may be coming as if you are not using the correct app and dysm file, you should use the build file created for device, not for simulator and repeat the crash on device and use crash memory location from crash log of device

Comment: Hey @kerni, I have used this way to find out crash info several times, so I dont find what is wrong content in this post, please do tell me ?

Comment: @Bhupendra: You are passing the app executable to atos and then say `It will give the line number and function Name in the code where your app get crashed.` This is wrong, since it will not provide the line number. You have to pass the dSYM file as a parameter instead. Second this is **NOT** where the app crashed, it is the last method call in the crashing thread from your app. This does not mean at all that you have a bug in that line or that the crash happened there.