# Random crash with UIAlertView

Tags: ios, crash, uialertview

I am getting random crashes with an `UIAlertView`. The crash does not always happen, and it is very random. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the stack trace :

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread  
Thread 0 Crashed:  
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x398685b0 objc_msgSend + 16  
1   UIKit                           0x33b59c4c -[UIAlertView(Private) _buttonClicked:]  
2   UIKit                           0x33aed0c0 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]  
3   UIKit                           0x33aed072 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:]  
4   UIKit                           0x33aed050 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:]  
5   UIKit                           0x33aec906 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:]  
6   UIKit                           0x33aecdfc -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:]  
7   UIKit                           0x33a155ec -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:]  
8   UIKit                           0x33a027fc -[UIApplication sendEvent:]  
9   UIKit                           0x33a02116 _UIApplicationHandleEvent  
10  GraphicsServices                0x356f25a0 _PurpleEventCallback  
11  GraphicsServices                0x356f21ce PurpleEventCallback  
12  CoreFoundation                  0x31bcf170 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__  
13  CoreFoundation                  0x31bcf112 __CFRunLoopDoSource1  
14  CoreFoundation                  0x31bcdf94 __CFRunLoopRun  
15  CoreFoundation                  0x31b40eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific  
16  CoreFoundation                  0x31b40d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode  
17  GraphicsServices                0x356f12e6 GSEventRunModal  
18  UIKit                           0x33a562fc UIApplicationMain
```

Comment: put relavent code here :)

Comment: Relevant code being the *buttonClicked:* method ;)

Comment: Can you post the buttonClicked/delegate method code you are using?

Comment: Are you adding any button in UIAlertView and assigning a target to it?? Or post alertViewDidClick methods code.

Comment: Could the UIAlertViewDelegate have been deallocated?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778350/how-to-solve-the-crash-issue-using-crash-log and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778350/how-to-solve-the-crash-issue-using-crash-log

Comment: Thanks for replies. If you notice the crash is not in app code. Not sure how the alert view is getting called here. As mentioned code does not crash on my device but this is from appstore crash report

Answer (score 0):

Your delegate is probably being cleaned up before the button press. This can happen (for example) if the view or that launched the alert is no longer on screen. Try turning on Zombie Objects (under Edit Scheme -> Run -> Diagnostics). If a deallocated object is sent a message, you'll get a message in the debug console.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. There are multiple alertviews in the app.Is there a way to figure out which one is causing it. As mentioned the problem is it does not happen on my device its from the appstore crash report.

Comment: Not from the stack trace. One area to look in your code is any place where you are automatically popping or dismissing views. For example do you have a save button where the current (like an edit) view is dismissed, but you display an alert if the operation fails? Or do you hide/show views when the application is foregrounded?